# RSA_private_decrypt return -1

Tags: openssl, rsa

I have a source file demo.cpp which can encrypt and decrypt data using openssl RSA. I can encrypt and decrypt data successfully.

However, if I create 2 files en.cpp and de.cpp and build them respectively. Then if I encrypt data using executable file en and decrypt the date using de.

Then RSA_private_decrypt will return -1.

Here is my encrypt and decrypt code.

```
 RSA_public_encrypt(strData.length(), (const unsigned char*)strData.c_str(), (unsigned char*)pEncode, pRSAPublicKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

and

```
RSA_private_decrypt(strData.length(), (const unsigned char*)strData.c_str(), (unsigned char*)pDecode, pRSAPriKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)
```

Comment: A convenient way to check your implementation is with the use of [`openssl rsautl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/rsautl.html). You can feed the output of `en.cpp` into `rsautl` and/or feed the output of `rsautl` into `de.cpp`. Additionally, you can use OpenSSL's [`ERR_print_errors()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html) and similar for more information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why separated exes can't encrypt and decrypt correctly.

However, I found a way out:

After encrypt the data, you have to encode the encrypted data by base64 first. Then, you can store the data or transmit it.

For decryption, you have to decode the data using unbase64 first. Then, you can use RSA_private_decrypt to decrypt it correctly.

Here is the link that implemented this solution.

https://gist.github.com/superwills/5415344

Comment: Maybe you were trying to write your ciphertext data into the file as text as opposed to binary data?